# VBA Text File Input for Reading and Writing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing in VB 2010 with a form with one button to be completely idiot.  I haven't done VB in awhile and noticed 2010 has a lot of changes compare when I did it a couple of years ago.

What I need done is it to read from a file and write two new separate files while writing to original.  It will read from a text file to get some contents and compare the current date.

The text content will be a serial and the next two columns will be dates.

```
    Dim iFileName As New StreamReader("G:\SAP In and Out\test.txt", False)
    Dim sFileExport As New StreamWriter(DateValue(Now)) + " SAP Export", False)
    Dim sFileImport As New StreamWriter(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 10, DateValue(Now)) + " SAP Import", False)

    Dim VTS As String 'Will be used to grab the VT serial
    Dim CurrentDate As Date 'Will be used to compare to grabbed dates
    Dim NextDateOut As Date 'Will be used to grab next date out value
    Dim NextDateIn As Date 'Will be used to grab next date in value

    'Setting a consistant value with daily'
    CurrentDate = DateValue(Now)

    Do While Not EOF(1)

        Input(iFileName),VTS,NextDateOut,NextDateIn

        If CurrentDate = NextDateOut Then

            'Write to the export File
            sFileExport.write(VTS)

            'Write under the just read line in the open file
            iFileName.write(/newline + VTS + /TAB + (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 20, DateValue(Now)) + /tab + (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 30, DateValue(Now)))

        ElseIf CurrentDate = NextDateIn Then

            'Write to import file
            sFileImport.Write(VTS)

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

But my syntax is off and it's obviously not running since I'm asking for help.
Please help and thanks in advance.  I've been working on this for hours and haven't had any positive results yet.

Comment: Could you post an example line of your input text file?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake I thought you was only using the import file for reading (not for writing too)

Comment: Sorry forgot to do that, example text file input would look something similar to this:

VT1000  3/26/2013  4/5/2013
VT1100  3/26/2013  4/5/2013
VT2000  3/27/2013  4/6/2013
VT2200  3/27/2013  4/6/2013

Comment: I can't seem to get it to do new line but after the second date it's the next line with VT etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think its right now, but i had to add an extra function so i could test it out.
I was receiving errors o the date format because I expect you use US date format (MM/DD/YYYY) and I use UK date format (DD/MM/YYYY).

Anyway you can strip the function out as I dont think you will need it, but I've left it in anyway so you can see whats going on its quite self explanatory and simply converts between the date formats, though it was made more difficult by the fact your days and month are not two digits long (no leading zero).

I hope it helps point you in the right direction and you can chop and change it to your preference.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim iFileName As New System.IO.StreamReader("c:\temp\vttest.txt", False)
    Dim iReadData As List(Of String)
    Dim Buffer As String

    'Read complete file into array
    iReadData = New List(Of String)
    Do While Not iFileName.EndOfStream()
        Try
            Buffer = ""
            Buffer = iFileName.ReadLine()
            iReadData.Add(Buffer)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'error or end of file
        End Try
    Loop
    iFileName.Close()

    'Not needed
    'Dim VTS As String              'This is in iLineData(0) after we split the line
    'Dim NextDateOut As Date    'This is in iLineData(1) after we split the line
    'Dim NextDateIn As Date     'This is in iLineData(2) after we split the line

    'Process
    Dim iFileUpdated As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\vttest_copy.txt", True)
    Dim sFileExport As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\vttest" & Replace(DateValue(Now), "/", "_") & " SAP Export.txt", True)
    Dim sFileImport As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\vttest" & Replace(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 10, DateValue(Now)), "/", "_") + " SAP Import.txt", True)
    Dim iLineData() As String

    'Setting a consistant value with daily'
    Dim CurrentDate As Date = DateValue(Now)
    Dim RowId = 0
    Do While RowId < iReadData.Count()
        iLineData = Split(iReadData(RowId), " ")
        iFileUpdated.WriteLine(iLineData(0) & " " & iLineData(1) & " " & iLineData(2))
        If CurrentDate = FormatDate(iLineData(1), "US", "UK") Then
            'Write to the export File
            sFileExport.WriteLine(iLineData(0))
            'Write under the just read line in the open file
            iFileUpdated.WriteLine(iLineData(0) & " " & (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 20, DateValue(Now))) & " " & (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 30, DateValue(Now))))
        ElseIf CurrentDate = FormatDate(iLineData(2), "US", "UK") Then
            'Write to import file
            sFileImport.WriteLine(iLineData(0))
        End If
        RowId = RowId + 1
    Loop
    sFileExport.Close()
    sFileImport.Close()
    iFileUpdated.Close()
    MsgBox("Finshed")
End Sub

'This section added because my PC is set to DD/MM/YYYY (UK)
'Expect yours is set to  MM/DD/YYYY (US)
Function FormatDate(ThisDate As String, ThisFormat As String, ThisTargetFormat As String) As Date
    Dim X As Integer = 0
    Dim Day1 As Integer = 0
    Dim Month1 As Integer = 0
    Dim Year1 As Integer = 0
    Dim Buf As String = ""
    If ThisFormat = "US" Then
        For X = 1 To Len(ThisDate)
            If Mid(ThisDate, X, 1) = "/" Then
                If Month1 > 0 Then
                    Day1 = Buf
                    Buf = ""
                Else
                    Month1 = Buf
                    Buf = ""
                End If
            Else
                Buf = Buf & Mid(ThisDate, X, 1)
            End If
        Next
        Year1 = Buf
    Else
        For X = 1 To Len(ThisDate)
            If Mid(ThisDate, X, 1) = "/" Then
                If Day1 > 0 Then
                    Month1 = Buf
                    Buf = ""
                Else
                    Day1 = Buf
                    Buf = ""
                End If
            Else
                Buf = Buf & Mid(ThisDate, X, 1)
            End If
        Next
        Year1 = Buf
    End If
    'reformat for output
    If ThisFormat = "US" Then
        If ThisTargetFormat = "US" Then
            'USA
            FormatDate = (Format(Month1, "00") & "/" & Format(Day1, "00") & "/" & Format(Year1, "0000"))
        Else
            'UK
            FormatDate = (Format(Day1, "00") & "/" & Format(Month1, "00") & "/" & Format(Year1, "0000"))
        End If
    Else
        If ThisTargetFormat = "US" Then
            'USA
            FormatDate = (Format(Month1, "00") & "/" & Format(Day1, "00") & "/" & Format(Year1, "0000"))
        Else
            'UK
            FormatDate = (Format(Day1, "00") & "/" & Format(Month1, "00") & "/" & Format(Year1, "0000"))
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Additionally i changed the file names so as not to overwrite the existing files (So i could compare the two files).

Most of the problems were arising from the back slashes in the dates in the FILENAMES - making the pc look for paths like /3/12 i guess it was translating the slashes into folder delimiters so I replaced them with UNDERSCORES on the fly.

Once you have edited the code to your preference you can OVERWRITE the existing file rather than generating a _copy.txt as thats how I tested with a _copy.txt in the sample.

## Update

Thanks for the feedback. Well its strange that your (generated) files are empty, because in the ones I have ONE has data the other is empty. This leads me to the assumption that your tweaks may have something to do with it?

For your reference I have posted them below.

**ORIGINAL FILE [VTSTEST.TXT]**

```
VT1000 3/26/2013 4/5/2013
VT1100 3/26/2013 4/5/2013
VT2000 3/27/2013 4/6/2013
VT2200 3/27/2013 4/6/2013
```

**COPY OF VTSTEST.TXT (after modification)**

```
VT1000 3/26/2013 4/5/2013
VT1100 3/26/2013 4/5/2013
VT2000 3/27/2013 4/6/2013
VT2000 16/04/2013 26/04/2013
VT2200 3/27/2013 4/6/2013
VT2200 16/04/2013 26/04/2013
```

Note: I expect the two longer lines are the ones inserted inbetween the existing four lines of text

**VTTEST06_04_2013 SAP Import.Txt**

This file was empty

**VTTEST27_03_2013 SAP Export.TXT**

```
VT2000
VT2000
```

Comment: First of all extremely thank you!!!  It seems to be in the right direction. I'm running through it and tweeking some of it.  It runs but the export and import files are blank I'm still trying to figure that one out.  I'm thinking I may have to do some data type conversion or something if I'm right?